# Return records affected from SQL Server 2008 to Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, vba, ms-access

I need a way to return the records affected from a SQL Server stored procedure and display it in a messagebox using VBA in my Access database. The following is the procedure I use to execute all stored procedures within Access...

```
Public Sub SP(exec As String)
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strConn As String

    strConn = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=;DATABASE=;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    With qdf
        .Connect = strConn
        .ReturnsRecords = False
        .SQL = exec
        .Execute
        .Close
    End With
    Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have anything referencing what stored procedure you want executed, so nothing will run.

Comment: I know how to run the stored procedure, I pass it as a parameter, for instance I may have a query (UPDATE tblProducts SET fldCost = 2 Where fldCost = 5), however, I need a way to return the records affected by this query and I don't know if there is a way to incorporate that into the above code or in some other way?

Comment: Ah. So `exec` contains the SQL string you are passing in?  I didn't notice that, and it wasn't explained in your question, so I thought maybe you were just missing that part.  Are you trying to return the number of records updated, or return the data from each of the records you updated?

Comment: Just the number of records updated, I know this is technically specified on the WHERE clause, but I'm looking for the simplest solution to get this value.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection`, `Database` and `QueryDef` all have a `.RecordsAffected` property.

Try the following:

```
Public Sub SP(exec As String)
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strConn As String

    strConn = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=;DATABASE=;Trusted_Connection=Yes"

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
    With qdf
        .Connect = strConn
        .ReturnsRecords = False
        .SQL = exec
        .Execute
        MsgBox Exec & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & .RecordsAffected & " Record(s) Affected."
        .Close
    End With
    Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub
```